# Linq query group by weight

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

`AllWordIDsAndWeightings` is a `Dictionary<int, double>` of unique ID's for words that appear in a search query, along with their corresponding weighting.

Given the following query:

```
returnedObjectIDs = new List<int>(db.WordObjectMaps
    .Where(c =>
        c.ForObjectTypeID == TopicObjectTypeID
        && AllWordIDsAndWeightings.Select(w=> w.Key).ToList().Contains(c.WordID)
    )
    .GroupBy(c => c.ForObjectID)
    .Select(c => c.Key)
);
```

I'd like to modify it so that:

The group by statement contains the sum of `word frequency * word weighting` for each word. Then I can order by this value descending and take the top `n` records.

Is this possible?

Comment: btw, `AllWordIDsAndWeightings.Select(w=> w.Key).ToList().Contains(c.WordID)` can be simplied to `AllWordIDsAndWeightings.Any(w => w.Key == c.WordID)`

Comment: @Aominè it's not much better, `Any` is slow. `AllWordIDsAndWeightings` is dictionary, and it has fast `ContainsKey` method

Comment: What does "contains the sum of" mean exactly? Contains where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
returnedObjectIDs = new List<int>(db.WordObjectMaps
    .Where(c =>
        c.ForObjectTypeID == TopicObjectTypeID
        && AllWordIDsAndWeightings.ContainsKey(c.WordID)
    )
    .Select(c => new { Word = c, Weight = AllWordIDsAndWeightings[c.WordID])
    .GroupBy(c => x.Word.Value * c.Weight) // replace with your condition
    .Select(c => c.Key)
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it needs to group by `c.ForObjectID` and the total weighting at some point.

Comment: @TomGullen add group and sort methods as you need